# Add N:M table with select values with asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm developing a simple form using ASP.NET Core 2.2, and between the tables that I have, there is Scripts and Tags, that have an N:M relationship.  I have a multiple select to choose between the tags in the file "CreateScripts.html" but in the end only one Tag is selected. I've searched on the documentation but couldnt find the answer. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Part of the class Scripts:

```
[Key]
public int idScript { get; set; }


[ForeignKey("Tags")]
[Display(Name = "Tags")]
public int idTags { get; set; }
```

CreateScripts.html selection:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Scripts.idTags" class="control-label"></label>
        </br>
        <select multiple="multiple" asp-for=" Scripts.idTags" asp-items="Model.listatag"> 
        </select>
  </div>
```

Create.html.cs:

```
 public async Task OnGet()
        {
            var linguagem = from l in _context.Linguagem
                            select l;
            l = await linguagem.ToListAsync();
            listatag = _context.Tags.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.idTags.ToString(),
                Text = x.nmTags
            });             
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Scripts Scripts { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            Scripts.dtcriacaoScript = DateTime.Today.Date;
            Scripts.dtultimoacessoScript = DateTime.Today.Date;
            Scripts.idVersao = Convert.ToInt32(Scripts.idVersao);
            Scripts.idLinguagem = Convert.ToInt32(Scripts.idLinguagem);
            Scripts.idTags = Convert.ToInt32(Scripts.idTags);

            _context.Scripts.Add(Scripts);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to select multiple tags you should move your idTags to an array of tags. try to change `int idTags` to `int[] idTags`

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks a lot!